# Current time PHP

Tags: php, time

I want to use the time function time() to output the expected waiting time of a patient.

I currently have the following fields;

```
 PatientID   Forename  Surname   Illness   Priority    Waiting Time
```

How would I incorporate the time function into PHP to get the current time for the following calculation;

```
 waiting time would be (the clock time - the arrival time)
```

Comment: You mean the [`time()`](http://php.net/time) function?

Comment: You could use `time();`.

Comment: What exacly are you trying to achieve that you couldnt just use the php date / time functions. http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php

Comment: Yes I know i can use this for example; $the_time = date('G:ia');
echo $the_time;  but do I have to store this in the database?

Comment: No,unless you are using it for data in the future such as logins, signups, creations, etc.

Comment: Question has been edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should store the [epoch/unix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) time in your database:

```
$the_time = time();
```

You can store all your different timestamps as these [epoch/unix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) times and later easily convert them to dates:

```
date( 'G:ia', $the_time );
```

You can also use the [epoch/unix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) times to easily determine how far apart two different times are:

```
$the_time_1 = "1363903644";
$the_time_2 = "1363900644";

$time_diff = $the_time_1 - $the_time_2;
$hours = $time_diff / 3600; // 60 * 60 = number of seconds in an hour
echo $hours . ' hours';
```

To respond to your request for a function to process waiting time:

```
$the_time_1 = "1363903644";
$the_time_2 = "1362900644";

echo waiting_time( $the_time_1, $the_time_2 );

function waiting_time( $time_1, $time_2 ) {

    $time_diff  = $time_1 - $time_2;
    $days       = floor( $time_diff / 86400 ); // 60 * 60 * 24 = number of seconds in a day
    $time_diff -= $days * 86400;
    $hours      = floor( $time_diff / 3600 ); // 60 * 60 = number of seconds in a hour
    $time_diff -= $hours * 3600;
    $mins       = floor( $time_diff / 60 ); // 60 = number of seconds in a minute

    return( $days . ' days, ' . $hours . ' hours, ' . $mins . ' minutes' );

}
```

Comment: Do I need to use timezone, as its displaying the time as one hour ahead

Comment: Yes, what is your timezone? This is the format for accomplishing that: date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');

Comment: Ireland, but I suppose I'll have to use UK

Comment: date_default_timezone_set( 'Europe/London' ); should work for you then

Comment: you have been very helpful, thankyou

Comment: if I want to get the arrival time from the "time" table; will I use something like this while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))

Comment: I would post that as a new question, it would be hard for me to answer that in a single comment

Comment: apologies will try with a select function first then as an array

Answer (score 0):

In database you should save time with `time()` function. That's good for sorting and more.
When you want to see the date with format, just use with `date('G:ia', $time);`

Good luck.

Comment: Can I just use time() within PHP for the calculation?